# QGIS layer symbology strange - suddenly with lower opacity

Tags: qgis-3, symbology

I have a shapefile where I set the Symbology to categorized. After defining the symbols suddenly the symbols have less opacity while the opacity slider says 100%. Is this a bug in QGIS 3.10? Is there a workaround to solve this problem?
[image: layer symbology with blending modes]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? Do you have overlapping features? Do you have activated layer blending modes?

Comment: the blending mode is "Normal"

Comment: Screensot would be even more helpful if it included the layers you have and map canvas

Answer (score 3):

There a two places where the opacity can be defined: A) for the entire layer (as shown in your screenshot) and B) per symbol.

You can set the "default" opacity of each symbol by clicking on the categorizer symbol color (before adding categories) or by clicking on the existing categories color.

[image]

[image]